# Numbers turned into a number turned into numbers (start with the smallest)

Tags: visual, number-sequence, sequence

**What number should replace the question mark? Explain why.**

---

[image]

**Hint 1**

> **Title:** Prime numbers turned into a composite number turned into prime numbers. 
>  **Arrangement of the squares**: It has nothing to do with a rainbow, instead it's a depiction of *symmetry*. The ROYGBIV colors are just there to let you know the order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 263

Reasoning

> Take the single digit prime numbers and concatenate them - **2357**.
>  Symmetrize this number as indicated by the arch in the diagram - **2357532**.
>  This is the composite number we create.
>  Now factorise this number as a product of primes $$2357532 = 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 83 \times 263$$
>  Note that this is the ordered factorisation as given in the diagram with **263** missing.

Comment: Nice work, this is it!